# Xamarin & Google Play App Signing

Tags: xamarin.android, google-play, android-signing

Has somebody enrolled into "Google Play App Signing" and tried it with a xamarin android app?

Since the enrollment is irreversible i would like to know, whether it is possible to sign xamarin apps (with VS archiving / command line build / CI build)

Answer (score 1):

I have enrolled. There are some problems, I have yet not been able to upload a new application but for existing applications there is no problem, just build it and use the tools to link your account in xamarin/vs and it uploads no problem.
I will post an update when I succeed in uploading a new application.